# Mostrar número de coincidencias entre dos tablas reacionadas

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Con el siguiente código relaciono la tabla clientes y la tabla viajes y se ordena en función del número de coincidencias de cientes encontrados en la tabla viajes.

```
$cliente = Cliente::select(DB::raw('clientes.id, clientes.name, clientes.apodo)'))
    ->leftjoin('viajes','clientes.id','=','viajes.cli_id')
    ->groupBy('clientes.id')
    ->orderBy(DB::raw('COUNT(viajes.id)'), 'DESC')
    ->get();
```

En la vista muestro la columnas clientes.id , clientes.name, clientes.apodo mediante el siguiente código

```
{{ $cliente->id}}
{{ $cliente->name}}
{{ $cliente->apodo}}
```

Me gustaría poder mostrar también el número de coincidencias encontradas por el cual se ordenan los datos, es decir, COUNT(viajes.id) en la tabla viajes, pero no soy capaz de conseguirlo.

No tengo claro si he retocar la consulta en el controlador o puedo conseguirlo directamente ya desde la vista blade.

modelo viaje.php

```
public function cliente() {

    return $this->belongsTo('App\Cliente', 'cli_id');
}
```

modelo cliente.php

```
public function viajes(){

    return $this->hasMany('App\Viaje', 'cli_id');

}
```

Este es el código final con el cual obtengo el conteo de los viajes que pertenecen a cada cliente y se ordenan el función de ese conteo.

```
clientes = Cliente::select(['id', 'name', 'apodo'])
          ->withCount('viajes')
          ->orderBy('viajes_count', 'desc')
          ->get();
```

Después el en la vista solo hay que aplicar las siguientes lineas para mostrar la información:

```
                @foreach ($clientes as $cliente)

                {{ $cliente->id}}

                {{ $cliente->name}}

                {{ $cliente->apodo}}

                {{ $cliente->viajes_count }}

            @endforeach
```

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que falta? ¿el conteo de todos los registros que da la consulta?

Comment: @Shaz Quisiera poder mostrar el conteo del numero de viajes que tiene cada cliente. La relación entre la tabla clientes y la tabla viajes de de uno a muchos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voy a asumir que tienes una relación `viajes` creada en tu modelo Cliente, para de esa forma aprovechar las capacidades de Eloquent y obtener el conteo directamente, como un atributo con el método withCount:

```
 $clientes = Cliente::select(['id', 'name', 'apodo'])
              ->withCount('viajes')
              ->get();
```

Y en la vista, iterando:

```
{{ $cliente->id}}
{{ $cliente->name}}
{{ $cliente->apodo}}
{{ $cliente->viajes_count }}
```

Aquí está la documentación respectiva: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models

---

Las llaves foráneas «personalizadas» deben estar definidas en ambos modelos:

```
public function viajes(){

    return $this->hasMany('App\Viaje', 'cli_id');

}
```

Comment: He añadio los modelos en la pregunta inicial. Cuando ejecuto el codigo me muestra el  siguiente error "Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'viajes.cliente_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select `clientes`.*, (select count(*) from `viajes` where `clientes`.`id` = `viajes`.`cliente_id`) as `viajes_count` from `clientes`)" No entiendo por que toma viajes.cliente_id si en el modelo esta definida la relación mediante la columna viajes.cli_id

Comment: Ya edité mi respuesta explicando como deben definirse las llaver foráneas que no siguen el estándar.

Comment: Perfecto, es uso lo que necesitaba muchas gracias. edito la pregunta inicial con el código final